# malloc issue causing variable to be overwritten

Tags: c, malloc

I have 3 global variables in my program. For some reason when I run `string2bin` on `pad` the contents of `binaryMessage` get overwritten and I can't figure out why. I increased the size of my `malloc`'s but that didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Note that `randomPad()` creates a string of random "hex" values, which should be converted to a  binary string representing the hex string.

```
char * temp;
char * binaryMessage;
char * pad;

void process_message(char *s)

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

        temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) *2048);

        binaryMessage = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) *2048);

        pad = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2048);

        process_message("test");

}


char * char2bin ( unsigned char c ){
      static char bin[CHAR_BIT + 1] = {0};
      int i;

       for ( i = CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            bin[i] = (c % 2) + '0';
            c /= 2;
       }

       return bin;
}

char* string2bin(char* str){
       int i;
       int len = strlen(str);

       sprintf(temp,"");
       for(i=0; i< len;i++){
             sprintf(temp, "%s%s",temp,char2bin(str[i]));
       }
       return temp;
 }

 char* randomPad(){
       int i;
       const char *hex_digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
       char * p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*242);

       // clear old pad data
       //sprintf(pad,"");

       // create random string of 242 hex chars to use as pad
       for(i = 0; i< 242; i++){
             sprintf(p,"%s%c",p,hex_digits[ ( rand() % 16 ) ]);
       }
       return p;
 }
 void process_message(char *s){
       binaryMessage = string2bin(s);
       printf("m %s\nbm %s\n",s, binaryMessage);

       //get random one time pad
       pad = string2bin(randomPad());

       printf("m %s\nbm %s\n",s, binaryMessage);
 }
```

My expected output is:

```
m test
bm 01110100011001010111001101110100
m test
bm 01110100011001010111001101110100
```

My actual output is:

```
m test
bm 01110100011001010111001101110100
m test
bm 0011011100110001001110010100000100110010001110000011100001000101001100110100010000111000001101010100001100110010001100110011011100110111001100010011100000110100010001100011000101000100001101010011100000110101010000100011011000111000001101110011100100110010001110000011001100110010001100010011001101000100001100110011010101000110001100000011000100111000010001000011000101000011010000100011001000110101001110010011000100110100001110000011010000110010010000110011010001000001001101110100000101000001001101010011100000111001001101010011000100110000001101000011010101000001001101010100001001000100001110010011011000110111001110000011000100110101001100110100010101000100001101010011010100110011001110010011010001000010010000010100001100110011001100010011001000110000010001010100001100110001001101100011100001000100001100010100011000110100001100010100010100111001010001000011011000110000001110010011011100110001010001100011001101000001010001010100011000110000010000110011010000110101010000010011100001000010001100000011100100110010010001010011001000110110001101010011001001000011010001100100010001000110001110000011011101000100010001010100011000110010001100010011000001000101001110000011011100110111010001010011010000110010001101110011011101000101001101110011000100111000001110010100010101000010001100100011010100110010001101100011011001000011001101000100010100110110010000010011001000110011001100100011010000110110001101100011011101000110001100110011100100110001001110000011001101000110001100010011100000110101010001100011010000110000001100000011011101000010001110010100010101000001010000100011011100111000010000110100011000110010010000110100001100110111010001100011000101000100001101010011000100110011001100010100000101000101001100110011000000110001001110010011000100110111010000110100001000111000010001100100011000110010001100110100001101000100001110000011000001000101001110000100001001000100010001100100011000110001001100010011000001000110
```

Comment: `randomPad` generates a string of 242 digits. Why would you expect a shorter string?

Comment: Thats correct, this should be output.

Comment: I print `binaryMessage` before and after I run `randomPad()`. `binaryMessage` should be unchanged, yet it is completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the errors alk pointed out, you have four more problems.

1- This:

```
char * p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*242);
```

Should be this:

```
char * p = malloc(sizeof(char)*243);  // Do NOT cast malloc
```

2- This:

```
sprintf(p,"%s%c", p, hex_digits[ ( rand() % 16 ) ]);
```

Should be this:

```
sprintf(p+i,"%c",hex_digits[ ( rand() % 16 ) ]);
```

3- You're missing this:

```
*(p+242) = '\0';
return p;
```

4- And finally, this line of code:

```
binaryMessage = string2bin(s);
```

Replaces the `binaryMessage` pointer with the `temp` pointer value.

The best advice I can offer? *Get rid of all the globals.* And you need to seed the random number generator with something unpredictable (current time, for example) or you'll get the same sequence of "random" numbers every time.

Comment: This line `char * p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*...` should be `char * p = malloc(sizeof(char)*...` or even more flexible `char * p = malloc(sizeof(*p)* ...`. `char` is different from `char*`.

Comment: Good catch. Edited to reflect the change.

Comment: Also `sizeof(char)` is `1` so you can get rid of that entirely.

Comment: @MattMcNabb True, but I think `sizeof(char)*243` shows the intent better than just `243`. Replacing the magic number with a named constant would be best, of course.

Answer (score 3):

These lines are critical:

```
sprintf(temp, "%s%s", temp, char2bin(str[i]));

...

sprintf(p, "%s%c", p, hex_digits[ ( rand() % 16 ) ]);
```

From [`sprintf()`'s man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html):

> Some programs imprudently rely on code such as the following

```
       sprintf(buf, "%s some further text", buf);
```

> to  append  text  to  buf.   However,  the  standards  explicitly  note  that  the results are undefined if source and destination buffers overlap when calling **sprintf()**, **snprintf()**, **vsprintf()**, and
>          **vsnprintf()**.  Depending on the version of gcc(1) used, and the compiler options employed, calls such as the above will **not** produce the expected results.